# Style which uses references attr in app widget

Tags: android, android-theme, attr, android-appwidget

I have `AppTheme` with some custom stylable attributes. For example `attr1`. I have style:

```
<style name="Style1">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/attr1</item>
</style>
```

When I use this style inside my activity layour for example it works fine. But when I'm using this style in app widget layout - it can't be instantiated. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. `android:attr` reference works fine in app widget.

Comment: I need to use theme related attributes. With drawable or color it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use your app resources for appWidget, they have separate context
you can only use remoteViews for styling

Answer (score 0):

The background is a drawable, did you try replace it with `drawable` or `color` resources?

```
<style name="Style1">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
</style>
```